# Unable to do multiple POSTs using Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, restful-authentication

I'm trying to programmatically login but am getting a `401` error. This is my code:

```
 with requests.Session() as s:
    resp = s.get(dydraLogin)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html5lib")
    csrfToken = soup.find('meta',{'name':'csrf-token'}).get('content')
    # print csrfToken
    payloadLogin = {
    'account[login]':key,
    'account[password]':'',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken,
    'next':'/'  
    }
    payloadPOST = {
    'url': sesameURL
    }
    headersPOST = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/n-quads',
    'Referer': dydraLogin,
    'User-Agent': 'python',
    'account[login]':key,
    'account[password]':'',
    'id':csrfToken,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken,
    'next':'/',
    }
    # paramsPOST = {
    # 'auth_token': key
    # }
    # print payload
    p = s.post(dydraLogin,data=payloadLogin, headers=dict(Referer=dydraLogin))
    print p
    try:
        q = s.post(dydraUrl,data=payloadPOST, headers=headersPOST)
        print q.text
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print e
```

This is the output:

```
<Response [200]>
401 Unauthorized
```

I am able to log in but the sebsequent POST of data fails. What do I need to do differently to execute the second POST correctly?

UPDATE 1

I tried regenerating the csrfToken but the error persists:

```
    url='http://dydra.com/username'
    resp_new = s.get(url)
        # print resp_new.text
        soup_new = BeautifulSoup(resp_new.text,"html5lib")
        csrfToken_new = soup_new.find('meta',{'name':'csrf-token'}).get('content')
        print 'csrf_new: ' + csrfToken_new

        payloadPOST = {
        'url': sesameURL,
        'account[login]':key,
        'account[password]':'',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken_new,
        'next':'/',
        }   

        headersPOST = {
        'User-Agent': 'python',
        'Content-Type': 'application/n-quads',
        'Referer': dydraLogin,
        }

        # paramsPOST = {
        # 'auth_token': key
        # }
        # print payload

        try:
            q = s.post(dydraUrl,data=payloadPOST, headers=headersPOST)
            print q.text
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print e
```

UPDATE 2:

I am able to access the dydraUrl if I use the authentication key in the url:

```
print s.get('http://dydra.com/username/repositories/rep_name/statements?auth_token=<key>').text
```

However, the 401 error persists when I use the URL inside payloadPOST.

Comment: The login page will send back a cookie that contains an authentication token that proves you logged in. You will need to send this cookie back with your future requests. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: Tried that, but the error persists. The code is in the UPDATE 1.